# Calculator Dot Function

Tags: calculator

I am currently creating a calculator with certain functions and new to apps developer.

Currently, the dot function is working fine, just that it has one issue. 
The dot repeat itself after another dot before eventually stopped. 
This resulted in either "1.2." or 1..2".
Whenever, there are two dots appeared, it created the NaN value which is not desired.
I do realised that the issue is originated from the "try" section, however I have not found a way to solve this. 
Any feedback is appreciated.

```
b_dot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                show.setText(show.getText().toString() + "");
                    try{
                        val2 = Double.parseDouble(show.getText().toString());
                        show.setText(show.getText().toString() + ".");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        if (toastMessage!= null) {
                            toastMessage.cancel();
                        }
                        toastMessage= Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Invalid Value",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toastMessage.show();
                    }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please add tags for programming language, and also for GUI toolkit/framework/environment you are using.

Comment: OT what is the return type of `show.getText()`? The name suggests "String", so you don't need a `.toString()`

Comment: in `show.setText(show.getText().toString() + ".");` you are always adding a ".", without checking whether there already is one.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you only want to add a dot if the string does not already have a dot? Or do you want to add dot first (to a temp variable copy), then test if number is still valid and only set the actual value if it is?

Comment: @hyde Yes, you are right. I only ant to add a dot if the string does not already have a dot.

Comment: So if string is currently valid double, you add the dot, and then you don't care if string becomes invalid or not. See the problem in your logic? You need to test if string *with the new dot* is valid double.

Comment: @hyde Yes, I got what you meant here. Is there any function to define the new dot?

Comment: Just put it into a temp variable. `String dotAdded = show.getText().toString() + ".";`